# Let $K \subset L$ be fields and $\tau \in L$ be transcendental over K. Then $\tau$ is algebraic over $K(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha \in K(\tau) - K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K \subset L$ be fields and $\tau \in L$ be transcendental over K. Show that $\tau$ is algebraic over $K(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha \in K(\tau) - K$

Any help with this question? I'd love a hint instead of a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element in $K(\tau)-K$ is a rational function in $\tau$, so there are polynomials $f,g$ with coefficients in $K$ such that
$$\alpha=\frac{f(\tau)}{g(\tau)}$$
Can you make a polynomial with a root of $\tau$ from this?

Comment: that's what i was trying to do! but i was not sure if the best approach was trying to construct this polynomial, or trying to do a more theoretical argument...

Comment: @raffa You can construct it from $f$, $g$, and $\alpha$. The equation I wrote is almost there.

Comment: oh my god, that's right! now i feel silly. i need to get better at this stuff. thanks haha

Comment: @raffa No problem.